# Separating if conditions for which there can be some overlapping cases

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements, enumerate

Given a pandas dataframe `wb`, which looks like this (in Excel, before bringing
it into pandas with `read_csv()`:

[image]

Column *ad_tag_name* is in groups of 3. I want to append **_level2** to every second of each group of 3, and **_level3** to the value of this column in every third of each group of 3, so I end up with something like:

[image]

I have decided to use mod division, with the logic that "if it divides evently by both 2 and 3, then append **_level3**; if it divides evenly only by 2, then append **_level2**. if it divides evenly only by 3, then append **_level3** Otherwise, leave it alone."

```
for index, elem in enumerate(wb['ad_requests']):
    if np.mod(index+1,2) == 0 and np.mod(index+1,3) == 0:
        wb.at[index,'\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"'] = wb.at[index,'\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"'] + "_level3"
    elif np.mod(index+1,3) == 0:
        wb.at[index,'\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"'] = wb.at[index,'\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"'] + "_level3"
    elif np.mod(index+1,2) == 0:
        wb.at[index,'\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"'] = wb.at[index,'\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"'] + "_level2"
```

Yet when I save the resulting CSV and examine it, I see:

[image]

The pattern is: *no suffix, _level2, _level3, level2, no suffix, level3, no suffix, level2, level3* and then this repeats. So it's correct in 8 out of 9 cases, but really that is an accident. I don't like the fact that there may be some overlap between the `if`s/`elif`s I have defined, and I am sure it is this flawed logic that it as the root of the problem.

How can we re-write the conditions so that they are properly achieving the logic I have in mind?

Python: 2.7.10
Pandas: 0.18.0

Comment: Whoever has downvoted the question 7 seconds after it was submitted has an ability to speed-read that I can only hope to achieve some day.

Comment: For the first if condition, should you also add `_level2` ?

Comment: If you mean the if that checks if both 2 and 3 divide evenly into _index+1_, what do you mean by "also add _level2"? In this `if,` I am trying (though my logic is clearly wrong) to catch the 6, 12th, 18th elements etc. where both 2 and 3 will divide evenly into _index+1, and I believe it's _level2 rather than _level3 I need to append to these.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

While pandas can provide some elegant shortcuts, it can also lead one down rabbit-holes of trial-and-error.

Sometimes going back to basics, to what Python provides built in, is the way to go.

```
for i in range(len(wb))[2::3]:
    wb.at[i,'\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"'] = wb.at[i,'\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"'] + "_level3"
for i in range(len(wb))[1::3]:
    wb.at[i,'\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"'] = wb.at[i,'\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"'] + "_level2"
```

Comment: Proof that while pandas can provide some elegant shortcuts, it can also lead one down rabbit-holes of trial-and-error, when sometimes going back to basics, to what Python provides built in, is the way to go.